# Difficulty Displaying CSS Customizations in Webpage Despite Successful Linking

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, weather, weather-api

I'm seeking assistance with a coding issue. I'm having trouble linking my styles.css file to my index.html. It visually looks like ive lnked the CSS file using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">`, but my webpage's customizations aren't showing up when I open it in a browser. Could you please provide guidance on resolving this issue and ensuring my code functions correctly?

When trying to resolve the issue of linking my styles.css file to my index.html, I followed the typical method of using the  tag with the appropriate attributes (rel, href, and type). I expected that by doing so, the styles defined in styles.css would be applied to my webpage when viewed in a browser. However, despite successfully linking the CSS file, the webpage's customizations fail to appear as expected.

Heres my html script:

Comment: Hi and welcome! there is too little information to know what's happening. Maybe paths are incorrect. It helps a lot if you provide some code to look, or a minimal reproduction of the error. Or at least visual of the other components interacting. All your images show is the CSS, maybe you uploaded the wrong images.

Comment: Are you refreshing the page? In some browsers you must use Ctrl+F5 to fully refresh the links, so the browser doesn't use an old, cached version of the css file. And, what Daniel said.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text. And you've now even posted same picture twice, and HTML is missing.

Comment: don't add this stuff as a comment but **EDIT** your question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.